# Eliminar datos mysql php

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

tengo una tabla hecha donde me muestra registros de una base de datos en mysql.En la tabla por cada registro se crea un boton que se llama eliminar y lo que quiero conseguir es que al dar click se elimine ese registro.

tengo este codigo hecho en usuarios.php

```
<?php
include_once('conexion.php');
$consulta = consultausu();

?>
```

entre el primer codigo php y el siguente esta es diseño de la web

```
<?php
while($variable = $consulta->fetch_assoc())
{
  ?>
  <tr>

    <td><?php echo $variable['nombre']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $variable['apellido']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $variable['correo']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $variable['contrasena']; ?></td>
    <td>
      <form>
          <input name="btneliminar" type="button" value="Eliminar" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary offset-2" onclick = "consultaeli();" />
      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <?php
}
?>
```

conexion.php

```
<?php  
//CONECTAMOS CON LA BBDD

$conexion = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "discografica");
if ($conexion->connect_errno) {
    echo "Fallo al conectar a MySQL: (" . $conexion->connect_errno . ") " . $conexion->connect_error;
}
$consultaeliminar='';

  function consultaeli(){
  global $conexion, $consultaeliminar;
  $borrar = "DELETE FROM usuarios where nombre='$variable'";
  return $conexion->query($borrar);
}
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema?

Comment: Cuando doi click al boton,no se borra ese registro

Comment: ¿Dónde defines $variable en el contexto consultaeli()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienas varias cosas tú pagina.

La primera, es que intentas eliminar un registro con una llamada `JAVASCRIPT`, cuando tu código esta en `PHP`, con lo que no te ha de funcionar.

La segunda es que tienes una condición en el `WEHERE`, pero en la llamada, no pasas ese parámetro.

Tienes varias soluciones, pero como no comentas, si usas `JQUERY`, te voy a dar una solución un tanto genérica, que te serviría.

Lo primero es cambiar el `HTML`, para poder llamar al `PHP`, que te ha de eliminar el registro.

```
<?php
while($variable = $consulta->fetch_assoc())
{
  ?>
  <tr>

    <td><?php echo $variable['nombre']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $variable['apellido']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $variable['correo']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $variable['contrasena']; ?></td>
    <td>
      <form method="GET" action="acciones.php?accion=consultaeli&nombre=<?php echo $variable['nombre']; ?>">
          <input name="btneliminar" value="Eliminar" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary offset-2"/>
      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <?php
}
?>
```

Fíjate que lo que hago crear el formulario, y en el `action`, llamar a un fichero acciones, que será en el que haga todas las operaciones.
Del botón de los dos tipos que tienes, he dejado solo el submit, que es el que lanzará el formulario.

El archivo **acciones.php**,tal y como lo tienes tú sería

```
<?php
    $conexion = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "discografica");
    if ($conexion->connect_errno) {
        echo "Fallo al conectar a MySQL: (" . $conexion->connect_errno . ") " . $conexion->connect_error;
    }
    else{
        $accion=$_GET["accion"];
        switch($accion)
        {
            case "consultaeli":

                $nombre=$_GET["nombre"];

                header("Location: pagina.php"); //pagina desde la que se hace la llamada

                $borrar = "DELETE FROM usuarios where nombre='$nombre'"

                mysqli_query($conexion, $borrar);
                mysqli_close($conexion);
            break;
        }
    }
?>
```

En caso de usar `JQUERY`, sería similar, pero el `FORM`, no lo tendrías que crear y la llamada la harias desde el evento `ONCLICK`

Answer (score 0):

El problemas es que tu tratas de activar una funcion php. Pero:

```
<input name="btneliminar" type="button" value="Eliminar" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary offset-2" onclick = "consultaeli();" />
```

el evento onclick de este botón estará buscando una función de javascript.

En esta página hay ejemplo similar a tu manera de programar:
http://www.uterra.com/base_datos_mysql/codigo_mysql.php?ref=eliminar_registros_de_una_base_de_datos

Pero te recomiendo aprendas a realizar CRUD (insertar, modificar, eliminar)